# Is it possible to upload a file through a web form on a mobile device?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, forms, file

In fairly recent versions of iOS and Android, is it possible to upload any arbitrary file to a web form?

Looking through Google and SO, this seems to not be the case for older versions, but what bout more recent versions either operating system?

If not, what are my alternatives? I don't have access to an iPhone, nor have I ever used one, so could you explain why this isn't the case and what my options are?

Comment: `to == through` ? Or `to == from` ?

Comment: Same difference as a form doesn't hold any data. Just directs it somewhere.